# How to browse line by line a csv then cell by cell in R

Tags: r, csv

Here is my code  :

```
smp <- read.csv2("tennis2.csv")
dim(smp)
names(smp)
str(smp)
smp$NbLigne[1]
for(i in smp$NbLigne){
  print(i)
}

Size <- nrow(smp)
print(Size)
# not working
# here is my problem
for(i in smp){
  print(i$NbLigne)
}
```

I would like to browse line by line my csv then for each line print the NbLigne cell of the line.

I've tried to do it this way  :

```
for(i in smp){
  print(i$NbLigne)
}
```

but it's not working.

Thanks and regards

Comment: `for (i in 1:Size) print(smp[i, "NbLigne"])`

Comment: If you wish to browse,  you might try `View(smp)`

Answer (score 0):

```
for(i in 1:nrow(smp)){
  row <- smp[i,]
  print(row$NbLigne)
}
```

or